# Unity3D [SerializeField] Menu Array not showing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

So I'm following Rugbug Redfern's tutorial on how to make Photon multiplayer but the Menu SerializeField array isn't showing. Please help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MenuManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static MenuManager Instance;

    [SerializeField] Menu[] menus;

    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    public void OpenMenu(string menuName)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < menus.Length; i++)
        {
            if(menus[i].menuName == menuName)
            {
                menus[i].Open();
            }
            else if(menus[i].open)
            {
                CloseMenu(menus[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OpenMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < menus.Length; i++)
        {
            if(menus[i].open)
            {
                CloseMenu(menus[i]);
            }
        }
        menu.Open();
    }

    public void CloseMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        menu.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Menu`?

Comment: Also please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!